# Why won't my Laravel app load?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, debian, php-7

The screenshot below shows what I'm seeing on my Chrome browser. I tried running `php artisan` but got same error output regarding the `log` class instead of the artisan help.

[image: Laravel App]

I am trying to get my Laravel app running on a docker container with Debian 8.5, Apache, and PHP7. I already have the same app successfully running on another docker container running Ubuntu with PHP5. The contents of `/var/www/html` on both containers point to the same folder on my laptop, I'm not sure if this is an issue. All necessary PHP extensiosn for Laravel are installed.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Dastur 5.1, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I needed to install the PDO MySQL driver. I had installed the PDO extension but it only had SQLite installed bydefault.